# Parsing information

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

I try to parse information about phones. Need phone: link, name, price , photo Now I have: link, name, price. So need just a little bit. My code now is looking like this:

```
h2>Telefonai Varle su photo</h2>
</br>
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
 $url = "https://www.varle.lt/mobilieji-telefonai/";

// Start from the main page
$nextLink = $url;

// Loop on each next Link as long as it exsists
while ($nextLink) 
{
    echo "<hr>nextLink: $nextLink<br>";
    //Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a url
    $html->load_file($nextLink);

      $phones=$html->find();
       /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       /// Get phone blocks and extract info (also insert to db) ///
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $phones = $html->find('a[data-id]');

    foreach($phones as $phone) 
    {
        // Get the link
        $linkas = $phone->href;
        // Get photo
        $foto= $phone->find('span[data-original]', 0)->plaintext;
        // Get the name
        $pavadinimas = $phone->find('span[class=inner]', 0)->plaintext;
        $pavadinimas = str_replace("Išmanusis telefonas"," ",$pavadinimas);


        // Get the name price and extract the useful part using regex
        $kaina = $phone->find('span[class=price]', 0)->plaintext;

        preg_match('@(\d+),?@', $kaina, $matches);
        $kaina = $matches[1];

        echo $pavadinimas, " #----# ", $kaina, " #----# ", $linkas,  " nuotrauka " ,  $foto         ,"<br>";

        //$query = "insert into telefonai (pavadinimas,kaina,parduotuve,linkas,foto) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
       //$this->db->query($query, array($pavadinimas,$kaina,"Varle.lt", $linkas,"https://www.varle.lt"+$foto));
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Extract the next link, if not found return NULL
    $nextLink = ( ($temp = $html->find('div.pagination a[class="next"]', 0)) ?      "https://www.varle.lt".$temp->href : NULL );

    // Clear DOM object
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);
 }
 ?>
```

Something wrong with photo parser. Get this errors:

Messages: called in Message: Undefined variable: selector Message: Trying to get property of non-object

also need code for rating star's

source of web

```
   <a href="https://www.varle.lt/mobilieji-telefonai/samsung-phone-i9300-galaxy-s3-      juodasbaltas.html" class="grid-item product  " data-id="426226"
title=" Samsung Phone I9300 Galaxy S3 Juodas/Baltas - Mobilieji telefonai">



<span class="left-border"></span>
 <span class="left-border-hover"></span>
<span class="right-border-hover"></span>
<span class="top-border-hover"></span>
<span class="bottom-border-hover"></span>


<span class="wishlist_button_cont">
    <span class="add_to_wishlist witem426226" data-id="426226">
        <span class="icon insert"></span>
    </span>
</span>


  <span class="img-container" style="position: relative;">


    <img src="/static/app/img/white_space.png?lazyyy" class="lazy" data-original="/static/uploads/products/235x195/26/sam/samsung-phone-i9300-galaxy-siii-onyx-black.jpg"
        alt=" Samsung Phone I9300 Galaxy S3 Juodas/Baltas - Mobilieji telefonai" />


  </span>
 <span class="title"><span class="inner"><span> Samsung Phone I9300 Galaxy S3    Juodas/Baltas</span></span></span>


<span class="prices">

<span class="old-price-discount">
    <span class="old-price">
        1149
        Lt<span></span>
    </span><br />
    <span class="discount"><span class="minus">-</span>290 Lt</span>
</span>

<span class="price">
    859 Lt
</span>

 </span>
 <span class="rating">

<span class="rating-star selected"></span>

<span class="rating-star selected"></span>

<span class="rating-star selected"></span>

<span class="rating-star selected"></span>

<span class="rating-star "></span>

<span class="count">(85)</span>
 </span>
```

Can anybody help me for that problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the rating, you have to count the number of span[class=selected] inside the span[class=rating]

```
$rating = count($phone->find('span[class=rating]')->find('span[class=selected]'));
```

Comment: and what about phone photo?

Comment: and this not working. Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in